# remaping save to space key in vim maintains space key's functionality in normal mode

Tags: vim

I have remapped `:w` to space key using `nnoremap <space> :w<CR>`, I'm able to save the file using the space key now but everytime I do this, the cursor moves due to the space key's functionality in normal mode. How can I press space and save without the cursor moving its position?

Comment: `nnoremap <space> <Left>:w<cr>` as a temporary solution

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem (using gvim 7.4).

Comment: Can you add some more details about your setup? I can't reproduce this behaviour either.

Comment: this is my vimrc if it helps: https://github.com/Neats29/vimrc/blob/master/vimrc I just checked and it seems like every time I press the space button, the cursor jumps 6 characters forward, no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You full mapping (taken from your `.vimrc`) is this:

```
nnoremap <space> :w<CR> " remap :w save to space button in normal mode
```

Unfortunately, you cannot append a comment like this, **the comment will be part of the mapping!**

Better switch to commenting above on a separate line:

```
" remap :w save to space button in normal mode
nnoremap <space> :w<CR>
```

If you absolutely must comment in the same line, you need to use the `|` Ex command separator (which must be escaped (`\|`) or written as `<Bar>` inside a mapping):

```
nnoremap <space> :w<CR>| " remap :w save to space button in normal mode
```

#### Bonus tip

`:write` forces a write. Your use of `<space>` suggests that you trigger that very often, almost unconsciously. You can make your mapping more efficient by switching to `:update`, which only writes if there are unpersisted changes:

```
nnoremap <space> :update<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks for the bonus tip :)